# proguard can't find referenced class

Tags: android, release, proguard

I m trying to run proguard on my release apk but I get lots of "can't find referenced class" error in my console.

```
[2014-05-06 17:35:05 - DesiDime] Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient extends or implements program class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
[2014-05-06 17:35:05 - DesiDime] Warning: com.google.api.client.http.protobuf.ProtoHttpContent: can't find referenced class com.google.protobuf.MessageLite
[2014-05-06 17:35:05 - DesiDime] Warning: com.google.api.client.http.protobuf.ProtoHttpContent: can't find referenced class com.google.protobuf.MessageLite
[2014-05-06 17:35:05 - DesiDime] Warning: com.google.api.client.http.protobuf.ProtoHttpContent: can't find referenced class com.google.protobuf.MessageLite
[2014-05-06 17:35:05 - DesiDime] Warning: com.google.api.client.http.protobuf.ProtoHttpContent: can't find referenced class com.google.protobuf.MessageLite
[2014-05-06 17:35:05 - DesiDime] Warning: com.google.api.client.http.protobuf.ProtoHttpContent: can't find referenced class com.google.protobuf.MessageLite
[2014-05-06 17:35:05 - DesiDime] Warning: com.google.api.client.http.protobuf.ProtoHttpContent: can't find referenced class com.google.protobuf.MessageLite
[2014-05-06 17:35:05 - DesiDime] Warning: com.google.api.client.http.protobuf.ProtoHttpContent: can't find referenced class com.google.protobuf.MessageLite
[2014-05-06 17:35:05 - DesiDime] Warning: com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory: can't find referenced class com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader
[2014-05-06 17:35:05 - DesiDime] Warning: com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory: can't find referenced class com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader
[2014-05-06 17:35:05 - DesiDime] Warning: com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory: can't find referenced class com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter
[2014-05-06 17:35:05 - DesiDime] Warning: com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory: can't find referenced class com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter
[2014-05-06 17:35:05 - DesiDime] Warning: com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonGenerator: can't find referenced class com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter
[2014-05-06 17:35:05 - DesiDime] Warning: com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonGenerator: can't find referenced class com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter
[2014-05-06 17:35:05 - DesiDime] Warning: com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonGenerator: can't find referenced class com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter
[2014-05-06 17:35:05 - DesiDime] Warning: com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonGenerator: can't find referenced class com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter
[2014-05-06 17:35:05 - DesiDime] Warning: com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonGenerator: can't find referenced class com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter
```

Below is my proguard-project.txt file , taken from [here](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/examples.html)

```
-injars      bin/classes
-injars      libs
-outjars     bin/classes-processed.jar
-libraryjars /home/vihaan/Downloads/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20131030/sdk/platforms/android-19/android.jar

-dontpreverify
-repackageclasses ''
-allowaccessmodification
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic
-keepattributes *Annotation*

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider

-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
    public void set*(...);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.content.Context {
   public void *(android.view.View);
   public void *(android.view.MenuItem);
}

-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    static ** CREATOR;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}

-keepclassmembers class * {
    @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface <methods>;
}
```

I have uncommented this line in my project.properties file

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
```

My libs directory contains the required libraries

[image]

I don't understand why I'm getting these errors ?

Answer (score 1):

As I can see you have problems with Gson and protobuf.
In order to use Gson with proguard include fillowing lines in your proguard-project.txt file:

```
# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature

# For using GSON @Expose annotation
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# Gson specific classes
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
#-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }
```

the whole example can be found [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/source/browse/trunk/examples/android-proguard-example/proguard.cfg)

in order to fix protobuf errors try:

```
 -keep class com.google.protobuf.** { *; }
```

Comment: I have put the sample file but I still get the warnings.

Comment: try uncommenting -keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; } and change names of models classes specific to your project: change this -> -keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }